Cassandra - What is the best way to resync/restore table between different data center?
I have Cassandra keyspace that is configured with one replica in three different data centers 
CREATE KEYSPACE edi_keyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc2': '1', 'dc1': '1', 'dc3': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
One of the tables' files in DC3 has become corrupted, and I need to resync this table from either DC1 or DC2.  What’s the best approach to restore and sync the table in DC3? Is repair the only option available?

Running a nodetool repair is still the best option, but it's not the only one. But when I've had issues getting repairs to complete in the past, a nodetool rebuild seems to work. The difference, is that repair offers more options around fine-tuning the keyspace and tables affected, while rebuild is essentially a blanket re-stream of all data for a node or keyspace.
Here are the links to the docs for both:

nodetool rebuild
nodetool repair


Thanks, Aaron. I have several tables in the keyspace, so rebuilding all the keyspace is not something that I can do . I forgot to mention that the table size is 16TB, and I have 42 nodes in each DC. I'm afraid that repair will kill my cluster because I need to restream the entire table . We thought to copy the Sstables and indexes of the table outside of the cluster and stream back the data using sstableloader , What do you think ? (We stopped the current writing to the table, so we can't overwrite new records in this procedure )

@EdiM In that case, I would give rebuild a shot. The thing about sstableloader, is that you kind of need to know which rows (tokens) belong to which node. Rebuild will do that. It's also faster, because it doesn't check the existing data first (like repair does).

I didn't understand what you mentioned about Sstableloade and knowing which row belongs to which node. Let's say that I'm copying the Sstable files from 10 nodes outside the cluster to a new exporter-cassandra server and place each file's node in a different folder (e.g/node1/edi_keyspace/table1,/node2/edi_keyspace/tables) then I'm stream back the data from the exporter-cassandra to the origin cluster(e.g sstableloader -d node5.com,node6.com  /node1/edi_keyspace/table1 ,sstableloader -d node5.com,node6.com  /node2/edi_keyspace/table1),Why I need to know which rows belong to which node?

@EdiM Nevermind, I mis-spoke. The sstableloader will indeed send data to whichever node owns it, so you don't need to worry about that. Starting with the sstableloader sounds like a good plan.
